# Is it possible to validate the column order when uploading data from flat files using aws copy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm uploading data from zipped flat files to redshift using `copy` command, I would like to understand if there is any way to validate that the column order of the files is correct? (for example, if fields are all `varchar` then the data could be uploaded to the wrong columns).

In the copy command [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-column-mapping.html) it shows that you can specify the column order, but not for flat files, but I was wondering if there are any other approaches that would allow me to check how the columns have been supplied (for example, uploading only the header row into a dummy table to check, but that doesn't seem a possibility).

Comment: what *exactly* do you want to validate?

Comment: that the order of the columns in the flat file is correct.

Comment: what do you mean by that? do you want to check header value of your text file with each column name?

Comment: for example if a process is set up to ingest a table with 3 columns, all varchar, in order a, b, c but somehow the order of the columns change in the flat file to say c, b, a then the table will still be uploaded without any error

Comment: trying to find a way that it could be highlighted when the file is provided with wrong column ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this inside Redshift. `COPY` doesn't provide any options to only load a specific number of rows or perform any validation.

Your best option would be to do this in the tool where you schedule the loads. You can get the first line from a compressed file easily enough (`zcat < file.z|head -1`) but for a file on S3 you may have to download the whole thing first.

FWIW, the process generating the load file should be fully automated in such a way that the column order can't change. If these files are being manually prepared you're asking for all sorts of trouble.

Comment: thanks for recommendation. processes have been agreed and automated etc, but would just be more comfortable if could have checks on our side, will investigate whether can extract from zip without having to move whole file.